# A paradox in differential calculus

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, fake-proofs, differential, paradoxes

Say I have a function $f=f(x,y)$ where $x,y$ are independent variables. 
Now, it is given that $p=x+y$.

It can be shown that, since $x,y$ are independent, we get
$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} \implies \frac{\partial p}{\partial x}=1+0 \implies \frac{\partial x}{\partial p}=1$$ and similarly $$\frac{\partial p}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial y} \implies \frac{\partial p}{\partial y}=0+1 \implies \frac{\partial y}{\partial p}=1$$

Now I can write that $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial p}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{\partial x}{\partial p}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{\partial y}{\partial p}$$
And using the above values, we get that
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial p}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot1+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot1=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}  \tag1$$

So if I replace $f$ by $p$ in $(1)$, which is quite valid since, like $f$, $p$ is also a function in $x,y$, we get that 
$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial p}=\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial p}{\partial y} \implies \large\color{red}{1=2}$$

How is this possible? Where is the error? Can someone point it out for me?

---

**Addendum** *as per Surb's answer and comments*:

If, as Surb concludes, for $x,y$ being independent, $\frac{\partial x}{\partial p}=\frac{\partial y}{\partial p}=0$, so I will get $\frac{\partial f}{\partial p}=0$ for all $f=f(x,y)$. But this is not true at all. How about $f=p^2=(x+y)^2$?

So where is the mistake?

Comment: What should $\frac{\partial x}{\partial p}$ mean? Unless you give it a *precise* meaning, you're just using an undefined quantity, so you can get everything you want except a paradox.

Comment: @egreg It means partial derivative of $x$ with respect to $p$.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat: How can $\frac{\partial x}{\partial p}\neq 0$ if $x$ is (as you pretended) independent of any other variable (and in particular of $p$) ?

Comment: Oh, really? Is $x$ a function of $p$? Ever heard of the implicit function theorem?

Comment: @Surb If, as you conclude, for $x,y$ being independent, $\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial p}{\partial y}=0$, so I will get $\frac{\partial f}{\partial p}=0$ for all $f=f(x,y)$. But this is not true at all. How about $f=p^2=(x+y)^2$?

Comment: @SchrodingersCat: If $x$ and $y$ independent of $p$, there is no reason to have $\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}=0$ and $\frac{\partial p}{\partial y}=0$, since $p$ can be a function of $x$ and $y$ (as you suggest at the beginning). But indeed, if $x$ and $y$ independent of $p$ and $f=f(x,y)$, then yes, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial p}=0$. I hope that answer to all your doubts...

Comment: @Surb Sorry it was a typo. I meant something and wrote something different. Please refer to the addendum part in my question. I have corrected it.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat: In this case, yes $\frac{\partial f}{\partial p}=0$ ! And if you set $f(x,y)=p^2$ this implicit means that $x,y$ are depending on $p$ (other wise, it has no sense). An other sense of $f(x,y)=p^2$ with $x$ and $y$ independent of $p$, it's that $p$ is fixed (and thus not a variable), and thus, you'll still have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial p}=0$, but the $p$ of $\partial p$ and the $p$ of $f(x,y)=p^2$ are not the same (since in the first case is a variable and the second case a fix number).

Comment: Using formula one is totally redundant because $ 1+1=\frac{\partial x}{\partial p}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial p}= \frac{\partial x+y}{\partial p}=\frac{\partial p}{\partial p}=1$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your mistake is thinking in terms of "dependent" / "independent" *symbols* without introducing precise mathematical meaning for that.

You can't say that $\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}=1$ implies $\frac{\partial x}{\partial p}=1$. $p$ is a function of two variables $(x,y)$, and to calculate $\frac{\partial x}{\partial p}$, you should introduce another variable, say, $q(x,y)$, such that $(p, q)$ form a coordinate system.

For example, let $q = x-y$. Now $(p,q)$ are a coordinate system, and we can express $x$ and $y$ in terms of them:

$$x=\frac{p+q}{2}$$
$$y=\frac{p-q}{2}$$

So, it now happens that $$\frac{\partial x}{\partial p} = \frac{1}{2} \color{red}{\neq} \left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}\right)^{-1}$$

Note that introducing an *other* coordinate instead of $q$ will affect $\frac{\partial x}{\partial p}$ too, so you can't speak of $\frac{\partial x}{\partial p}$ alone.

Answer (score 1):

By using $\frac{\partial x}{\partial p}\neq 0$ and $\frac{\partial y}{\partial p}\neq 0$, you make $x$ and $y$ depending on $p$ ! Therefore, it has no sense to consider $p(x,y)$. Indeed, if $p(x,y)$ would have sense, then $p$ would be dependent and independent of $x$ and $y$, which is impossible.

Comment: Note that $x,y$ are independent. They do not depend on anybody.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat, if $x$ and $y$ would be independant of $p$, then $\frac{\partial x}{\partial p}=\frac{\partial y}{\partial p}=0$. Since those partial derivative are $1$, they are necessarily depending on $p$.

Comment: So should they be $0$ or should they be $1$?

Comment: @SchrodingersCat: The problem it the meaning that you give to $\frac{\partial x}{\partial p}$. I presume that it's the derivative of the inverse function. But this is not $\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}\right)^{-1}$. But it's anyway not a good notation.

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong at very beginning.

$p$ is a function change with $x$ and $y$.

If only $x$ changes and $y$ is invariant, $\frac{\partial x}{\partial p}=1$ and $\frac{\partial y}{\partial p}=0$ because $\frac{\partial x}{\partial p} = \lim_{\triangle p->0} \frac{\triangle x}{\triangle p} $

If only $y$ changes and $x$ is invariant, $\frac{\partial y}{\partial p}=1$ and $\frac{\partial x}{\partial p}=0$.

One can guess that $\frac{\partial y}{\partial p}+\frac{\partial x}{\partial p}=1$.